# (sub)section with number, subsubsection with letter - \ref shows only the letter

Tags: cross-referencing

when I try following code, everything works as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\alph{subsubsection})}
\begin{document}
\section{A Section}
\subsection{A Subsection}
\subsubsection{A Subsubsection}
\label{testlabel}
Hello world.
\par
In \ref{testlabel} I wrote: Hello world.
\end{document}
```

This will print 1.1.1.

But if I enable the command in the comment, I just get a) instead of the expected 1.1.a)

In fact I want the section to appear as a) ... and the reference as 1.1.a without brace.

Any ideas?

Comment: The section or the subsubsection should appear as a) and the reference as 1.1.a, effectively vice versa?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. But David Carlisle has given a working answer already. Thx all

Comment: Ok, I'll delete my version then, it's of no use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

For any LaTeX counter the macro `\p@...countername` is the prefix
used in references. Normally it is used in nested enumerate to get exactly the effect where the list label just shows one level and a reference shows the
expanded form.

The default macros assume that the print form of the final counter is the same 
in both places, so as you want to lose the `)` you need the prefix macro to remove it, as here, or as in egreg's answer not add it to the counter format, and instead consider the `)` part of the section heading format.

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\alph{subsubsection})}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@subsubsection}{\thesubsection.\protect\eatbracket}
\makeatother
\def\eatbracket#1#2{#1\ifx)#2\else#2\fi}

\begin{document}
\section{A Section}
\subsection{A Subsection}
\subsubsection{A Subsubsection}
\label{testlabel}
Hello world.
\par
In \ref{testlabel} I wrote: Hello world.
\end{document}
```

Comment: How about adding some mortar to this?

Comment: @Werner you mean that documentation thing?

Comment: ...riiiight. :)

Comment: Note that this exploits the alphabetic counter; it will not work with numeric counters, after the ninth subsubsection.

Comment: @Werner added some words

Comment: @egreg but this _is_ an alphabetic counter:-)

Answer (score 4):

It's better to add the parenthesis where it belongs, rather than removing it afterwards. This can be accomplished by a simple redefinition of `\@seccntformat`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \csname the#1\endcsname
  \csname suffix@#1\endcsname % this does nothing unless \suffix@... is defined
  \quad
}
% the subsubsection number is just a letter
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\alph{subsubsection}}
% but references will also have “section.subsection.” in front of the letter
\renewcommand{\p@subsubsection}{\thesubsection.}
% define \suffix@subsubsection
\newcommand{\suffix@subsubsection}{)}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A Section}
\subsection{A Subsection}
\subsubsection{A Subsubsection}\label{testlabel}

Hello world.

In \ref{testlabel} I wrote: Hello world.

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is also scalable. Suppose you want a normal interword space between the `a)` and the title, while keeping the `\quad` for higher levels. Then you can modify the code as

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \csname the#1\endcsname
  \@ifundefined{suffix@#1}%
    {\quad}%
    {\csname suffix@#1\endcsname}%
}
% the subsubsection number is just a letter
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\alph{subsubsection}}
% but references will also have “section.subsection.” in front of the letter
\renewcommand{\p@subsubsection}{\thesubsection.}
% define \suffix@subsubsection
\newcommand{\suffix@subsubsection}{) }% parenthesis and space
\makeatother
```

[image]

The second solution with also a fix for the table of contents (again, between the parenthesis and the title just a normal space seems best).

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \csname the#1\endcsname
  \@ifundefined{suffix@#1}
    {\quad}%
    {\csname suffix@#1\endcsname}%
}
% the subsubsection number is just a letter
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\alph{subsubsection}}
% but references will also have “section.subsection.” in front of the letter
\renewcommand{\p@subsubsection}{\thesubsection.}
% define \suffix@subsubsection
\newcommand{\suffix@subsubsection}{) }% parenthesis and space
\renewcommand{\l@subsubsection}[2]{%
  \@dottedtocline{3}{3.8em}{3.2em}{\let\numberline\subsubsection@numberline#1}{#2}%
}
\def\subsubsection@numberline#1{#1) }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A Section}
\subsection{A Subsection}
\subsubsection{A Subsubsection}
\label{testlabel}
Hello world.
\par
In \ref{testlabel} I wrote: Hello world.

\section{Whatever}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This would generally be the better approach, I guess. And nice addition with the space. I just saw in the real life case that in the TOC I get `a` with your solution, in Davids `a)`. But this has to be `a)`

Comment: @musicman Added the fix for the table of contents

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the `\thesubsubsection` the contents of `\thesubsection` as well

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\alph{subsubsection})}
\begin{document}
\section{A Section}
\subsection{A Subsection}
\subsubsection{A Subsubsection}
\label{testlabel}
Hello world.
\par
In \ref{testlabel} I wrote: Hello world. 
\end{document}
```

Yielding

[image]

Comment: The reference still appears with the parenthesis which is not desired; I think a more complicated approach is required to make it not appear i nthe reference.

Comment: Hmm I understand the problem. But I want `a)` in the section heading and the full reference  `1.1.a` in `\ref`.

Comment: @musicman: Please make it clear if you mean the section heading or the subsubsection heading for a) ... this is a little bit confusing.